# ShareKit - SHKFacebook: Is there a way to get the authorization_token ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I was wondering if there was a way to get access to the authorization_token returned by the oauth process during a Facebook login in SHKFacebook?

I already have the facebook_access_token. What I'm trying to get access to is the authorization_token returned during the first half of the oauth2 login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBUserId"]) {
 // user login facebook
  }
```

Twitter:

```
SHKTwitter *checkTwitterLoging = [[SHKTwitter alloc] init];

if ([checkTwitterLoging isAuthorized]) {
 // user loving twitter
 }

 [checkTwitterLoging release];
```